# How to detect if an item appears in a new line (within a textarea) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I would like to create an array from the content of a textarea. 
The textarea contains a variable list of names (each only one word without spaces).

So far I have the following, my only problem here is that the single names are not separated with a comma but instead only appear in separate lines with one name per line and I don't know how I can detect this. The content of this textarea is created manually so a user would either hit Enter after every name or they would copy / paste a list of names from an Excel table.

How can I achieve this ? I think the only thing I need to change is `split(',')`.

**My jQuery:**

```
var arrUsers = $('#ntid').val().split(',');
var xmlUsers = '<users>';               
    for(i=0; i<arrUsers.length; i++) {
        xmlUsers += '<ntid>' + arrUsers[i] + '</ntid>';
    }
    xmlUsers += '</users>';
```

**Example HTML (shortened):**

```
<textarea rows="7" class="form-control" id="ntid">
    name1
    name2
    name3
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\n` instead of comma and trim the splitted values.

```js
var arrUsers = $('#ntid').val().split('\n');
var xmlUsers = '<users>';               
for(i=0; i<arrUsers.length; i++) {
  var val = $.trim(arrUsers[i]);
  //check if there is any text after trimming
  if(val != "") {
      xmlUsers += '<ntid>' + val + '</ntid>';
  }
}
xmlUsers += '</users>';
alert(xmlUsers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="7" class="form-control" id="ntid">
    name1
    name2
    name3
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works great ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)